# IOException when attempting to File.Replace a file on encrypted drive

Tags: c#, encryption, filesystems

Our application is writing a simple xml document to disk.  In an attempt to avoid corruption, we write the new data to temporary file, then `File.Replace` it into the appropriate location.  Xml files are ~4MB.

We recently started encrypting the hard drives and now the logs are showing occasional failures when writing these files.

Here is some code to show the problem:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string srcFile = "srcFile.xml";
            const string dstFile = "file.xml";
            const string bakFile = "file.bak";

            const int iterations = 100;
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                var tempFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", i, tempFileName);

                File.Copy(srcFile, tempFileName);
                File.Replace(tempFileName, dstFile, bakFile);
            }
        }
```

On my system, running this for 100 iterations will regularly produce the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Unable to remove the file to be replaced.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
   at System.IO.File.InternalReplace(String sourceFileName, String destinationFileName, String destinationBackupFileName, Boolean ignoreMetadataErrors)
   at System.IO.File.Replace(String sourceFileName, String destinationFileName, String destinationBackupFileName)
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.FileReplace(Int32 iterations) in C:\dev\Test\TestSerialization\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 149
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\dev\Test\TestSerialization\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 76
```

Wondering if this was something specific to `File.Replace`, I attempted copying both the source and destination files to temporary files and using `MoveFileEx` with the `MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING` flag to get them into their final location. This produces an `Win32Exception: Access is denied` error with about the same frequency.

I've ran this code on various systems.  Those with hard drive encryption throw this above exception.  I have had to bump up the iterations (to ~500) for some, but I'm unsure whether that's due to the encryption software or the system specs.  All drives are NTFS.  I've tried Dell Data Security, BitLocker, and McAfee Total Protection Endpoint Encryption, all produce the same result.

Systems without encryption haven't produced the error after multiple runs of 5000 iterations.

1. What is really going on here? Does the encryption hold on to the files after Copy/Move/Replace operations but still allow the C# calls to return?  Or is encryption a red herring?
2. What's the solution?  Just catch the failure and retry?

Comment: When a file is encrypted, the operating system may hold onto it for a short period of time after the file is closed or deleted to ensure that the encryption process is completed. This can cause issues with file operations that assume the file is immediately available for use.

Comment: Either you try catch it like you said, or you can try using `File.Delete` and `File.Move` instead of `File.Replace` to move the temporary file into place.